# Can I add multiple Microsoft providers to Firebase project

Tags: firebase, azure, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase app with an enabled Microsoft provider. Can I easily add another Microsoft provider and connect it to another Azure AD project?

[image: enabled providers]